# phpMyAdmin 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, server, internal-server-error

today I built a droplet from DigitalOcean, I installed LAMP and phpMyAdmin without any problem. After that for copy my old website to my new droplet, I tried to use ftp. I used vsftpd, created a user for it, changed the ufw permissions little bit, changed some settings from vsftpd.conf and that's all. Now I am trying to access phpmyadmin but

`Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request....Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at xxx.xx.xxx.xxx Port 80`

sudo service apache2 status

`OUTPUT:`

netstat -ln | grep -E ':80|443'

`OUTPUT:` `tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN`

Comment: Is apache actually listening on port 80? Did you check apache error_log to see more details about the error?

Comment: to be honest, I am not sure what I am looking, when I open error_log and how to check is apache listening 80. :/

Comment: What os are you using and what version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 sorry I forget to say at first.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to diagnose the exact problem from your Error, I would start with:

1. Check that the server is running correctly (in Ubuntu `sudo service apache2 status`)
2. Check Apache is listening on port 80 (in Ubuntu `netstat -ln | grep -E ':80|443'`
3. Make sure the phpmyadmin permissions are correct (directory and files usually needs to be owned by the web server user `www-data` with proper access permissions)
4. Check the apache virtual host file to see if you have the right `Directory` configuration (usually phpmyadmin will have sample values in the setup file)

If all of that does not point you in the right direction to fix the issue you will need to start looking through your logs in `/var/log/apache2/` and get some more detailed error messages.

Comment: I sent the output of `netstat` and `apache status` but the photo is not visible

Comment: config.inc.php file needed to have the same owner as apache for me... it was apache in centos

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 doesn't mean Apache listening issue. you should open your log file to see what problem occurred. usually, Apache error log is located in this PATH
`/var/log/apache2/error.log` if you didn't specify a custom log file for your virtual host. append error from the end of file in your question.

Comment: There're lots of lines but i think `[pid 6448] (2)No such file or directory: [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:$` this one is myadmin's log

Comment: you can find the related error by opening the URL again, see the log file and find the time that you checked the URL.

Comment: yes, i did it, this message that i sent is the log when i open the URL again.